# Alias to complicated Template Typename

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I have the following  definition in file Segment.h

```
template<typename T, typename VecType = mat::vec3_gen<T> > class Segment
{
    // class
}
```

Instead of having `typename VecType = mat::vec3_gen<T>` I want to use some alias for the type
and be able to use it outside the file also. how can I do it?

Comment: Create a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) in the class?

Comment: I don't understand the question/problem. Just write `typename VecType = SomeAlias<T>` instead. Or you simply want to be able to refer to `VecType` outside of Segment class? Just write inside the template `using AVecType = VecType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the type `VecType` depends on `T`, you can make the type alias a member of `Segment`.

```
template<typename T>
class Segment {
public:
    using VecType = mat::vec3_gen<T>;
};
```

Now you can use it in other code:

```
auto vec = Segment<int>::VecType;
```

Comment: Why can not we do `template<typename T> using VecType =  mat::vec3_gen<T>` and simply `VecType<int> something;`?

Comment: @Const oh you could do that too! I assumed OP had a somewhat complex Segment class, and that it made sense for the alias to reside in the class.